# How to know number of tokens used in LLM SQL agent?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, chatgpt-api

I am using the below sql_agent to query through my database:

```
agent = create_sql_agent(llm=llm, toolkit=sql_toolkit, agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
handle_parsing_errors=True, verbose=True, max_execution_time=200,
max_iterations=1000)
response = agent.run(prompt.format_prompt(question=query))
```

Is there any way to count the total number of tokens(prompt tokens+query tokens+query_result tokens+thought tokens+action tokens+observation tokens+tool tokens) used by this agent.

I have used the below approach without good results:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/llms/token_usage_tracking
When I try to verify the number of output tokens result with openai website, the number of tokens are off by large margin.
for example:
[Output of the tried approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgRsb.png)

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/16798. It looks like there are some proposed workarounds that you can try. Please take a look at the issue.